# Draw outside bounding box in fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXmTC/276/) setting width and height to circle object:

`circle.set({ radius: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x), width : 50,height :50 });`

so bounding box will be 50*50

its drawing fine for fabricjs 1.5.0, but not in newer version. 
I want to draw outside bounding box, how can I acheive it?

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Comment: @TimHarker Sorry,that is not what I looking for, u no need to set width height also, it will work , because it sets width and height according to radius. but the problem is in new version, it does not draw outside selection area

Comment: @Durga did you ever figure this out! I have the same problem. And wow did I waste a lot of time before I realized this is something that change sometime after 1.5.0

Comment: @byoungb still having the issue, need to change either old one, or else need to write according to new

Comment: @byoungb u can put `objectCaching: false` to draw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });

var circle, isDown, origX, origY;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
  isDown = true;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  origX = pointer.x;
  origY = pointer.y;
  circle = new fabric.Circle({
    left: pointer.x,
    top: pointer.y,
    radius: 1,
    strokeWidth: 5,
    stroke: 'red',
    objectCaching : false,
    originX: 'center', originY: 'center'
  });
  canvas.add(circle);
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  circle.set({ radius: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x), width : 50,height :50 });
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
  isDown = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

use [objectCaching](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#objectCaching):false to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this...

```
circle.set({ radius: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x), width : 50,height :50 });
```

To this...

```
var newAbsValue = Math.abs(origX - pointer.x);
circle.set({ radius: newAbsValue, width : newAbsValue * 2, height : newAbsValue * 2 });
```

Here's your JSFiddle updated, http://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/8rb8Lahb/.

Comment: I want for some other shape, not for circle... I want like previous version, as it was drawing outside the bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. In my case i was trying to draw line outside the bounding box of rectangle. I have validated from other examples that it is not possible to do it in new versions of fabric js. This makes sense as it might cause some other problems. So, you have to figure out something else. In my case i am using path to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: add `objectCaching: false` to your rectangle object, it will draw